# How to maintain a Github fork of a popular project with submodules

Tags: git, github, fork, project, git-submodules

I have the same question posed at

[How to maintain a Github fork of a popular project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288511/how-to-maintain-a-github-fork-of-a-popular-project)

So, I wish to make a fork of a popular project, make a few minor tweaks, and throughout time I want to keep in sync with the changes going on in the master project.

Except that my popular project that I am working with has a bunch of submodules.

So when I:

(1) add a remote repository called xxx that points to the original master branch of the original project

(2) do a git pull xxx master

It pulls in the master project's files and it reports that there are conflicts.  When I do a git status I see:

```
added by us:    external/binary-reference-assemblies
```

I see this in .gitmodules, so I understand this is a submodule.

What should I do at this point to ensure that I get the latest files for this submodule, so I can subsequently push everything back to my forked repository?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31821219/6309), try and do a `git submodules update --init` just before the merge, in order to add that submodule.

Note that a submodule would by default only display the exact SHA1 it represents, in a [detached HEAD way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20797186/6309).
A `git submodule update --remote` would update that reference to the latest commit.
See more at "[`git submodule update --remote` vs `git pull`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19621245/6309)".