# Merging after directory got turned into submodule

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-submodules, git-merge

I find that working with git submodules, I often encounter problems merging between commits which do contain a given submodules and those which represent the same code as a normal directory. Small reproducing example:

```sh
# Create one project, to be used as a subproject later on
git init a
cd a
echo aaa > aa
git add -A
git commit -m a1
cd ..

# Create a second project, containing a as a normal directory initially
git init b
cd b
mkdir a b
echo aaa > a/aa
echo bbb > b/bb
git add -A
git commit -m b1

# Replace directory with submodule
git rm -r a
git submodule add ../a a
git commit -m b2

# Try to create branch from the pre-submodule state of affairs
git checkout -b branch HEAD^
```

This already gives an error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    a/aa
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

In order to avoid the error, I deinitialize all submodules first:

```sh
# Create feature brach starting at version without submodule
git submodule deinit .
git checkout -b branch HEAD^
echo abc > b/bb
git commit -a -m b3
```

As you can see, the feature branch is completely unrelated to the submodule, modifying a different set of files. Which makes this whole problem particularly annoying.

```sh
# Try to merge the feature branch
git checkout master
git merge branch
```

This fails again, with an error message I don't fully understand:

```
CONFLICT (file/directory): There is a directory with name a in branch. Adding a as a~HEAD
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I get the same error if I do a `git submodule update --init` before the `git merge branch`. I don't see any `a~HEAD` anywhere, neither in my directory tree nor in the output from `git status`, which reads like this:

```
On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

    modified:   b/bb

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    added by us:     a
```

If I do `git add a` as suggested, I get another error:

```
error: unable to index file a
fatal: updating files failed
```

If I do `git submodules update --init` just before the merge, then I can do `git add a` successfully. But if I forget to do so, and then try doing that after the merge, I receive this error message:

```
Submodule 'a' (…/a) registered for path 'a'
Skipping unmerged submodule a
```

**How do I recover from this situation?** Something other than `git merge --abort`, since I'd like to use it for things like `git rebase` as well, and since in some scenarios (don't know how to reproduce) I couldn't even abort the merge cleanly, and had to do a hard reset instead.

How can I avoid it in the first place? Is there some magic setting which makes git do the right thing with submodules vs. directories during merges, so that I don't have to manually post-process a merge which only modifies files unrelated to the submodules?

Comment: FYI the `--abort` flag works for rebase as well.

Comment: @user880772: Yes, but it aborts the whole rebase, which means considerable effort might get lost if there were some conflicts along the way.

Comment: Git [doesn't handle submodule merging](https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/). Not in its usual magical way. If you don't want to forget running submodule update before a merge, you can turn "merge" into an alias (I feel horrible suggesting that). I don't see a clean way around this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you should not add a, the merge is not supposed to change it. What you should run is

```
git reset a
```

So you *ignore* the "chage" for a.

PS: apparently git merely checks existense of a directory, so if you

```
git submodule deinit a
rmdir a
```

before merging, it will succeed. Not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem when I merge code that contains folder that need to convert to submodule.

I solved it by using `BFG --delete-folders` to remove the folder from the new source code, and `git gc` to clean up the repository, then I will have `git rebase` without any conflicts.